# responsive elements layout for mobile

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

Sorry if this is an easy question but It took me almost days and still couldn't fix it.
I have a wordpress website and am using a 4 column design for showing our services.
In desktop view they are being showed as I want them to (next to each other), but in mobile view, they are not. I changed the column settings but still no luck.
Here's picture if it helps.
Any ideas please?

[desktop view](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/12/4e6626ebe902cdc72b102364f3a1d8e6-full.jpg)

[mobile view](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/3/12/6a8e6d6ffaba37b17e46c72160a0b9e6-full.jpg)

Comment: To help you, you need to provide the html and css code.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used `flexbox` to achieve it. thanks

```css
.parent{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child{
  border: 2px solid black;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      
  </div>
    <div class="child">
      
  </div>
    <div class="child">
      
  </div>
    <div class="child">
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much.
just to make sure I do it right, I should copy the first code to CSS file using the editor, and the second one to Page.php using editor. Right?

Comment: yes.. top part is the css code and bottom is html code